# FLUTTER - Tiempo real

Tags: http, flutter, dart, websocket

Buen día!, necesito saber si es posible implementar websocket con un backend php-mysql que actualmente funciona con protocolo http.
He revisado posts sobre uso de websocket pero ninguno de ellos maneja conexiones a bases de datos mysql a través de php.

El código actual mediante http es:

```
List<Solicitud> solicitudes = [];
  Future<List<Solicitud>> _capturaSolicitudes(String maestro) async {
    solicitudes = [];
    var res = await http.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Read.php?maestro=${maestro}");
    var jsonData = json.decode(res.body);
    setState(() {
      for(var i in jsonData){
        Solicitud solicitud = Solicitud(
            i["ID_SOLICITUD"],
            i["ID_PERSONA"],
            i["NOMBRE_PERSONA"],
            i["PROM_EVAL_PERSONA"],
            i["TOKEN"],
            i["FECHA"],
            i["DESCRIPCION"],
            i["ESTADO"]
        );
        solicitudes.add(solicitud);
      }
    });
    print(solicitudes.length);
    _registros = solicitudes.length;
    return solicitudes;
  }
```

Lo que necesito es habilitar un canal de comunicación bidireccional con el servidor de modo de no tener que hacer tantos llamados para mantener fresco el listview en tiempo real.

Gracias.!

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y es muy amplia, puede que termine cerrada, considera editar y mejorar tu duda.

Comment: Gracias!, nuevamente editado.